# Visual Studio ,Configuration Properties->Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, configuration

I run my program from some project ,using 
"`Configuration Properties -> Debugging`"

When I press F5,before starting to run the program it compiles the project...I don`t want  to compile the project,but just start execution of what I defined in the 
"Configuration Properties -> Debugging".
(The program executable exists)

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option that controls this is not directly associated with a project; it is under the general Visual Studio options.

Choose the menu item `Tools\Options`.  Then go to `Projects and Solutions\Build and Run`.  There is an option named `"On Run, when projects are out of date:`.  You can choose between "Always build", "Never build", "Prompt to build".

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with build configuration, but if you want to debug a .exe that you built, you can start it and use Visual Studio's Attach to Process ( Tools -> Attach to Process) to bind yourself to that .exe and debug it.